# Is there any way in Oracle to skip a value in a select when it has been already shown?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Sorry because maybe it's a silly question but honestly I don't know how to handle it. Let's imagine  that after executing a `select` with a `group by` clause I have the following information:

```
col1    col2    col3
---------------------
value1  optionA  1
value1  optionB  5
value2  optionA  3
value2  optionB  4
```

But I would like to obtain the following:

```
col1    col2    col3
---------------------
value1  optionA  1
        optionB  5
value2  optionA  3
        optionB  4
```

In other words, I don't want to show a previously shown value if it's the same (in this case, value1 and value2)

Is this feasible with Oracle? if the answer if yes, would you kindly point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but you need to tell us what's the ordering criteria.

Comment: Although you can do this in pure SQL (as @TheImpaler shows, +1), that's the sort of thing that is generally a bit suspect to do in pure SQL.  Whatever tool you have to display results to the human user probably has options to format the results.  And this is the sort of thing that usually is more appropriate in the user interface layer than in SQL (if only because then the UI person can tweak it later when someone wants to change the way the data is displayed without needing to futz with the SQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what's the ordering criteria for the rows so I'll assume it's (`col1`, `col2`).

The query you want should look like:

```
select
  case when col1 = lag(col1) over(order by col1, col2) 
       then null
       else col1
  end as col1,
  col2, 
  col3
from t
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention but you are absolutely right. Ordering criteria would be col1 and col2. I will give it a try and thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: It works. I didn't know the functions LAG and LEAD and they clearly open new horizons. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you were on SQL*Plus and used Oracle version which doesn't support analytic functions, you could have used its **break** command. I guess that's not the case nowadays, eh?

Originally:

```
SQL> with temp (col1, col2, col3) as
  2    (select 'value1', 'optionA', 1 from dual union all
  3     select 'value1', 'optionB', 5 from dual union all
  4     select 'value2', 'optionA', 3 from dual union all
  5     select 'value2', 'optionB', 4 from dual
  6    )
  7  select col1, col2, col3
  8  from temp
  9  order by col1, col2;

COL1   COL2          COL3
------ ------- ----------
value1 optionA          1
value1 optionB          5
value2 optionA          3
value2 optionB          4
```

Let's break it:

```
SQL> break on col1
SQL>
SQL> /

COL1   COL2          COL3
------ ------- ----------
value1 optionA          1
       optionB          5
value2 optionA          3
       optionB          4

SQL>
```